# What new fish were added in the 1.1 update?

Tags: ridiculous-fishing

The July 25th 1.1 update to *Ridiculous Fishing* mentions "a few new fish" added, but I don't see their entries in the Fish-o-pedia. What are they, and where can I find them? Also what are the new Friend Fishes and what is the fish that asks to be raised "into the skies"?

Comment: Not sure about the rest, but [this forum post](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=181844&page=68) suggests that the new top hats may allow you to get the "raise into the skies," but you'll need to be prepared to spend a lot of money.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new "Friend Fish" represent your friends from Game Center. You can encounter them in Maelstrom, and the depth the fish will be at will be at your friends' max depth reached in Maelstrom. If a friend "JimFisher" has reached a depth of 725m, then at 725m you'll see a tiny fish with a text bubble above it that says "JimFisher". If you catch a blue friend fish, then it will be added to your Fish-o-pedia under the name "Blue Friend" (but won't show up until then).

Finding a friend fish means you've just beaten a friend's top score. When the friend fish is flying through the sky with your friend's name on it, this would be a great time to take a screen shot to rub it in their face.